Error Connecting to PostgreSQL Database in Multi-Container Azure Container Instances (ACI) Setup
I’m currently deploying a multi-container setup using Azure Container Instances (ACI) and I’m facing issues with connecting to a PostgreSQL database container from a Node.js application container. Here’s a detailed description of the setup and the issue I’m encountering:
Setup:

PostgreSQL Container: Using postgres:16 image, configured with environment variables for user, password, and database.
Node.js Application Container: Custom Docker image with a Node.js application that needs to connect to the PostgreSQL database.
YAML Configuration:

Both containers are defined in the same container group in the YAML file.
PostgreSQL container listens on port 5432.
Node.js container is trying to connect to PostgreSQL using the container name postgres and the same port 5432.
apiVersion: '2021-10-01'
location: eastus
name: myContainerGroup
properties:
  containers:
  - name: backend
    properties:
      image: myrepo/nodejs:latest
      ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 80
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1
      environmentVariables:
      - name: PORT
        value: 80  # Ensure the app listens on port 3000 internally
      - name: DATABASE_HOST
        value: postgres  # Name of the PostgreSQL container
      - name: DATABASE_PORT
        value: 5432
      - name: DATABASE_USER
        value: postgres
      - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
        value: postgres123
      - name: DATABASE_NAME
        value: postgres
  - name: postgres
    properties:
      image: postgres:16
      ports:
      - port: 5432
      environmentVariables:
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: admin123
      - name: POSTGRES_USER
        value: postgres
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: postgres
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1   
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  ipAddress:
    dnsNameLabel: myApp
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 80

Issue:
When the Node.js application tries to connect to the PostgreSQL database, I receive the following error:
Error connecting to PostgreSQL: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:120:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres'
}


